# How to sort a poker hand to find the straight both high and low?

Tags: php, sorting

Let's say I have a deck of cards represented by an array like the following.

```
$cards = [
    "AS"  => ["sort" => 14, "suite" => "S", "value" => 11],
    "AC"  => ["sort" => 14, "suite" => "C", "value" => 11],
    "AD"  => ["sort" => 14, "suite" => "D", "value" => 11],
    "AH"  => ["sort" => 14, "suite" => "H", "value" => 11],

    "KS"  => ["sort" => 13, "suite" => "S", "value" => 10],
    "KC"  => ["sort" => 13, "suite" => "C", "value" => 10],
    "KD"  => ["sort" => 13, "suite" => "D", "value" => 10],
    "KH"  => ["sort" => 13, "suite" => "H", "value" => 10],

    "QS"  => ["sort" => 12, "suite" => "S", "value" => 10],
    "QC"  => ["sort" => 12, "suite" => "C", "value" => 10],
    "QD"  => ["sort" => 12, "suite" => "D", "value" => 10],
    "QH"  => ["sort" => 12, "suite" => "H", "value" => 10],

    "JS"  => ["sort" => 11, "suite" => "S", "value" => 10],
    "JC"  => ["sort" => 11, "suite" => "C", "value" => 10],
    "JD"  => ["sort" => 11, "suite" => "D", "value" => 10],
    "JH"  => ["sort" => 11, "suite" => "H", "value" => 10],

    "10S" => ["sort" => 10, "suite" => "S", "value" => 10],
    "10C" => ["sort" => 10, "suite" => "C", "value" => 10],
    "10D" => ["sort" => 10, "suite" => "D", "value" => 10],
    "10H" => ["sort" => 10, "suite" => "H", "value" => 10],

    "9S"  => ["sort" => 9, "suite" => "S", "value" => 9],
    "9C"  => ["sort" => 9, "suite" => "C", "value" => 9],
    "9D"  => ["sort" => 9, "suite" => "D", "value" => 9],
    "9H"  => ["sort" => 9, "suite" => "H", "value" => 9],

    "8S"  => ["sort" => 8, "suite" => "S", "value" => 8],
    "8C"  => ["sort" => 8, "suite" => "C", "value" => 8],
    "8D"  => ["sort" => 8, "suite" => "D", "value" => 8],
    "8H"  => ["sort" => 8, "suite" => "H", "value" => 8],

    "7S"  => ["sort" => 7, "suite" => "S", "value" => 7],
    "7C"  => ["sort" => 7, "suite" => "C", "value" => 7],
    "7D"  => ["sort" => 7, "suite" => "D", "value" => 7],
    "7H"  => ["sort" => 7, "suite" => "H", "value" => 7],

    "6S"  => ["sort" => 6, "suite" => "S", "value" => 6],
    "6C"  => ["sort" => 6, "suite" => "C", "value" => 6],
    "6D"  => ["sort" => 6, "suite" => "D", "value" => 6],
    "6H"  => ["sort" => 6, "suite" => "H", "value" => 6],

    "5S"  => ["sort" => 5, "suite" => "S", "value" => 5],
    "5C"  => ["sort" => 5, "suite" => "C", "value" => 5],
    "5D"  => ["sort" => 5, "suite" => "D", "value" => 5],
    "5H"  => ["sort" => 5, "suite" => "H", "value" => 5],

    "4S"  => ["sort" => 4, "suite" => "S", "value" => 4],
    "4C"  => ["sort" => 4, "suite" => "C", "value" => 4],
    "4D"  => ["sort" => 4, "suite" => "D", "value" => 4],
    "4H"  => ["sort" => 4, "suite" => "H", "value" => 4],

    "3S"  => ["sort" => 3, "suite" => "S", "value" => 3],
    "3C"  => ["sort" => 3, "suite" => "C", "value" => 3],
    "3D"  => ["sort" => 3, "suite" => "D", "value" => 3],
    "3H"  => ["sort" => 3, "suite" => "H", "value" => 3],

    "2S"  => ["sort" => 2, "suite" => "S", "value" => 2],
    "2C"  => ["sort" => 2, "suite" => "C", "value" => 2],
    "2D"  => ["sort" => 2, "suite" => "D", "value" => 2],
    "2H"  => ["sort" => 2, "suite" => "H", "value" => 2],
];
```

I want to be able to sort any arbitrary number of cards such that I can find the winning straight based on the sort order. I tried using a function like this.

```
function sortCardsBySortOrder(Array $cards, $reverse = false): Array {
    uasort($cards, function($a, $b) use($reverse) {
        $result = $a['sort'] <=> $b['sort'];
        if (!$reverse) {
            $result *= -1;
        }
        if ($result == 0) {
            $result = $a['suite'] <=> $b['suite'];
        }

        return $result;
    });
    return $cards;
}
```

From there I can easily detect if the cards are sequential and thus make up a straight in poker.

However, the problem is with the Ace as it can be both high and low. How would I be able to detect a straight without changing the `sort` field in the array? Or if I need to absolutely change it how would I do so without impacting the fact that the cards still need to be sorted as Ace high when I reorder the entire deck?

For example, in the poker hand `A, 2, 3, 4, 5` this is considered a straight as the **Ace** can be both a 1 or an 11 depending on where it best fits. So in the hand `A, K, Q, J, 10` the Ace is high. These are both straights but affect the sort field for the Ace. What's the best way of dealing with this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by basically breaking down the check for straight into two functions: `isStraight()` and `isLowStraight()`. If `isStraight()` fails, which checks for a straight based on an ascending sort order and counts Ace as high, then it will return `isLowStraight()` which checks for a straight in an ascending sort order and counts Ace as low. Basically the `isLowStraight()` function looks for an Ace and if one is found it moves it from the bottom of the sorted list to the top i.e. `array_unshift($cards, array_pop($cards))`, such that it is now considered the lowest possible card instead of the highest.